# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column does not exist LINE 1

Tags: django

I've created a boolean column in an existing Model and Migrated. I can see the column in the table with default values. but while running ./manage.py test, I'm getting the below errors.

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column xxxx does not exist
LINE 1:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column xxxx does not exist
LINE 1:
```

Comment: It's common to use a different database for the test runner. Looks like the migration was not applied to the test database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: yeah I'm using different database for tests. Not sure why migration files are not executed in test db. Is there any way to trace what causing issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your migrations are conflicted or not applied.
Look into the migrations folder, you need to look for the last two migrations, open them and look for the boolean field you added, delete it in both files, then run makemigrations and migrate commands.

If that failed, start deleting The migration files one by one (starting with latest file), run makemigrations and migrate commands each time you delete a file. That should work.

Just know that the migrations files are dependent on each other.

Also know that you could delete the entire migrations folder and it will initialize again if you run makemigrations command but use that as last resort.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see my migration file in django_migrations in test database, but it is working fine in regular database. Also because of the added migration file , last 2 migrations files are also not migrated. is there any way to trace what is causing the issue with migration files?

Comment: Migrations folder is not in a database but inside your django app.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably happening because, somehow, there's a mismatch between:

1. The migrations that were *actually* applied to the db.
2. The migrations that Django *thinks* were applied to the db.

In order to fix this, run the migrate command for each individual migration until they are applied.

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> xxxx_migration_name
```

*make sure to pass the actual migration name (without the `.py` extension) not the file name.

When an error is raised, add `--fake` to the command like so:

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> xxxx_migration_name --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

I found above error caused by trying import the models directly into migration scripts, so when django running specific version of migration, it conflicted correct model version. (your model may be updated, but version of migration your are trying to run is bit older)

Never directly import models in your migrations scripts, instead do like below as mentioned
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/writing-migrations/

```
    from models import MyModel # DONT DO THIS

    def gen_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
        MyModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "MyModel") 
        # INSTEAD INTIALIZE LIKE  THIS WILL CORRECTLY PICK THE MODEL version
        for row in MyModel.objects.all():
            row.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
            row.save(update_fields=["uuid"])
    
    
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
        dependencies = [
            ("myapp", "0004_add_uuid_field"),
        ]
    
        operations = [
            # omit reverse_code=... if you don't want the migration to be reversible.
            migrations.RunPython(gen_uuid, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
        ]
```

Answer (score -2):

use:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

after that:

```
python manage.py migrate
```